# Token based authentication for both Web App and Web API using Azure AD B2C

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, azure-ad-b2c, http-token-authentication

**Scenario:**
Both Web application and Web API need to be authenticated and protected from the server side.

**Requirement:** 
Web application is serving the contents for the browser and browser should be  calling Web API directly (i.e. Browser to API).

**Question:**
Is it possible to authenticate both Web APP and the API using tokens?

Any sample code or clear direction would be highly appreciated.

---

Normally web applications are authenticated using cookies and APIs are authenticated using tokens.There are some sample projects available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) but they are either browser to API (SPA token based) or Server side Web App calling API from server to server.

**UPDATE 1**

App is saving the `TokenValidationParameters` and used `bootstrapContext.Token` within the app controller to grab for server to server communication.

As per @dstrockis, I'm trying to grab the `id_token` from the Web App soon after the end of validation (not within the app contrller).

I'm using `SecurityTokenValidated` invoker in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.Notifications` within the `Startup` class. `SecurityTokenValidated` receives a parameter of type `SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>` but I'm not sure where to find the `id_token` within it. Method is below.

```
private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
{
    return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
        // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
        MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
        AuthenticationType = policy,

        // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
        ClientId = clientId,
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,

            //NEW METHOD INVOKE ************************************
            //******************************************************
            SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated

            //******************************************************
        },
        Scope = "openid",
        ResponseType = "id_token",

        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            SaveSigninToken = true
        },
    };
}



//NEW METHOD ************************************
private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(
       SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage,
                       OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
{
    //QUESTION ********************************************************
    //How to find the just saved id_token using incoming parameter, arg
    //*****************************************************************

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Instead of `SecurityTokenValidated`, I tried `AuthorizationCodeReceived` and it's not getting called at all. As discussed here, my [redirect url does have an ending slash](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/445) as well.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Our ASP.NET OpenID Connect middleware which supports AAD B2C is built to rely on cookie authentication from a browser.  It doesn't accept tokens in a header or anything like that for securing web pages.  So I'd say if you want to serve HTML from your web app in the classic way, you need to use cookies to authenticate requests to the web app.

You can definitely get & store tokens within the browser and use those to access your web API, even if you use cookies to authenticate to the web app. There's two patterns I'd recommend:

- Perform the initial login using the OpenID Connect Middleware, initiating the flow from the server side as described in the samples.  Once the flow completes, the middleware will validate the resulting `id_token` and drop cookies in the browser for future requests.  You can instruct the middleware to save the `id_token` for later use by using the line of code written [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L22).  You can then somehow pass that `id_token` down to your browser, cache it, and use it to make requests to the API.
- The other pattern is the inverse.  Start by initiating the login from javascript, using the single page app pattern from the B2C documentation. Cache the resulting id_tokens in the browser, and use them to make API calls. But when the login completes, you can send a request to your web app with the `id_token` in the body, triggering the OpenID Connect middleware to process the request and issue a session cookie.  If you want to know the format of that request, I'd recommend inspecting a regular server side OpenID Connect flow.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question and adding here for the future reference.

After a successful validation, `id_token` can be accessed by invoking the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification. Code sample is below.

```
private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(
       SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage,
                       OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
{
    //Id Token can be retrieved as below.
    //**************************************
    var token = arg.ProtocolMessage.IdToken;

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

However, saving this directly into a browser cookie may not be secure.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? When is this method executed? How do you implement the solution?

Comment: All these done within the Startup class in Startup.Auth.cs in the App_Start directory within the web application (not the API). You need to sort out the authentication for both Web App and the API first. There is a link, in the original post, for sample projects.